# Template function that can take standard map with different keys types and print them out differently

Tags: c++

I need to create a template function that can take in `map` type with `<int, string>` and `<pair<int,int>, string>` and print the key values. For the `<int, string>` map, I only want to print the key type `int`, and for the `<pair<int, int>, string>` map, I want to print the `pair.first` value. It seems like both statements get executed even when the condition is not met. Any way to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using intMap = std::map<int, std::string>; 
using pairMap = std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string>; 

template<class Map> 
void Validate (Map &map)
{
    if(typeid(intMap)==typeid(map))
    {
         std::cout << "intmap "<<std::endl; 
         for(auto const &i : map)
         {
                std::cout << "key = "<<i.first<<std::endl; 
         }
    }
    else 
    {
          std::cout << "pairmap"<<std::endl; 
          std::cout << "key = "<<i.first.first<<std::endl; 
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
    intMap map1 = {{1, "map1"}}; 
    pairMap map2 = {{{10,20},"map2"}};

    Validate(map1);
    Validate(map2); 

     return 0;
  }
```

I expect:

`Validate(map1)` will output 1
`Validate(map2)` will output 10

But, I get this error instead:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: If you do different things depending on the argument type, then why not use normal overloading?

Comment: You could also just use overloading to overload the `<<` stream operator, so you have one function that prints `i.first` and the normal overload resolution will select either the standard one for `int`, or your overload for `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Or combine both variants: Overload the function for printing the header, and then call another function to do the map output which uses the overloaded `<<` operator.

Comment: It's not related to the answer, since `typeid` is the wrong tool here, but if you do use `typeid`, you ***must*** `#include <typeinfo>` before that, otherwise your program is invalid. More about `typeid`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: they are not both executed, they are both checked by the compiler. They must be valid even when they are not executed

Answer (score 4):

`typeid` is the wrong tool for the job (and it's the wrong tool almost every time you think of using it). It doesn't do anything here - regardless of the result, both branches of `if` must have valid code. That's not possible here.

Since you seem to only allow two types and the implementation is vastly different for different types, why not use overloading instead?

```
void Validate (const intMap &map)
{
    std::cout << "intmap "<<std::endl; 
    for(auto const &i : map)
    {
        std::cout << "key = "<<i.first<<std::endl; 
    }
}

void Validate (const pairMap &map)
{
    std::cout << "pairmap"<<std::endl; 
    //missing a loop here presumably
    std::cout << "key = "<<i.first.first<<std::endl; 
}
```

If you really need everything in one function, `if constexpr` should be used with type traits to resolve the branch at compile time (`typeid` is runtime mechanism):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Map> 
void Validate (Map &map)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Map, intMap>)
    {
        std::cout << "intmap "<<std::endl; 
        for(auto const &i : map)
        {
            std::cout << "key = "<<i.first<<std::endl; 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "pairmap"<<std::endl;
        // again, forgot loop here
        std::cout << "key = "<<i.first.first<<std::endl; 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `constexpr if` to do the check at compile time and `std::is_same_v` to check if types are same as shown below:

```
template<class Map> 
void Validate (Map &map)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Map, intMap>)
    {
         std::cout << "intmap "<<std::endl; 
         for(auto const &i : map)
         {
                std::cout << "key = "<<i.first<<std::endl; 
         }
    }
    else 
    {
          std::cout << "pairmap"<<std::endl; 
          for(auto const &i : map)
          std::cout << "key = "<<i.first.first<<std::endl; 
     }
 }
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/19P8jPhaa)